# calling the PTSN from a browser

Tags: sip, voip, webrtc

I have a webpage with a dial button and I want to be able to make outbound phone calls and listen for inbound calls. What are my options? I've looked at WebRTC but I don't understand what asterisk (or freeswitch?) do. If the the user has a VOIP account then what needs to be done for the webpage to connect to that account and how do I get started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are WebRTC (only in the later browsers) or a browser plugin.

In the plugin case it will generally be a fully fledged SIP & RTP stack that will let you send and receive calls to a SIP Provider who will in turn gateway calls to the PSTN for you. Asterisk/FreeSWITCH etc. aren't needed unless you want calls from the plugin to go through your own server. The SIP Provider will be using a product along those lines.

If you use WebRTC then you can take advantage of a native browser javascript API to initiate a VoIP call. If you want to make and receive calls to the PSTN, as opposed to between other WebRTC supporting browsers, then you will need some kind of signalling gateway to translate between [ROAP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jennings-rtcweb-signaling-01) (which is the signalling protocol used by WebRTC) to SIP (or another VoIP signalling protocol).

The approach I'd recommend would be to use something like [phono](http://phono.com/). It will mean your calls go through someone else's servers but it's a quick and easy way to get started.

Comment: Phono looks interesting, especially to get started. If the user of my web app already has a SIP account at one of the many VOIP provider then do I need to create an asterisk/freeswitch server instance or can I connect the webphone on the webpage directly to the VOIP provider?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get phono to use a 3rd party provider for an outgoing call. As far as I'm aware phono only lets you forward to an anonymous SIP URI. You could possibly use my service, sipsorcery.com, to hook into 3rd party providers from phono but even that could be tricky if you need to do it on a per user basis.

Comment: ROAP was replaced by JSEP for WebRTC early in 2012: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-00. Despite the name, JSEP is more of an architecture than a protocol -- WebRTC doesn't specify mechanisms or protocols for signaling. As well as Phono, you may want to take a look at Zingaya: http://zingaya.com.